# Creating a new GIT branch from three branches while leaving them intact

Tags: git

So I am working in a team now, and I have three PR's, all on top of our `development` branch. For demo-purposes, I want to create a single branch with the contents of the three branches combined, but *without* touching the actual/original branches (because when I have feedback on the PR's I want to still be able to work on the original branches.

So for example, I have the following situation:

```
 Development ----> Commit1 - Commit2 - on Feature-Branch1
             |\
             | \--> Commit3 - Commit 4 - on Feature-Branch2  
             \----> Commit5 - Commit 6 - on Feature-Branch3
```

(my git branch drawing skills are somewhat limited, but I hope you get the gist)
and I want to achieve the following

```
Development ---> Commit1 - Commit2 - Commit3 - Commit4 - Commit5 - Commit6 - on demo-features-branch
```

while leaving the original three feature branches intact.

What would the best approach be?

Is there a way to copy a branch into/as a new branch? (and then I can rebase the branches on top of each other) Or should I just sherry-pick all the commits into a new branch (which will definitely work, but it seems like there should be a better way).

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout Development
git branch demo-features-branch
git checkout demo-features-branch
git merge Feature-Branch1
git merge Feature-Branch2
git merge Feature-Branch3
```

This will merge all of your branches into a demo branch while leaving your original feature branches unchanged.

Comment: Good answer. Not to nitpick, but let's note that you can replace the first three commands with `git checkout -b demo-features-branch Development` to the same effect.

Comment: Also, this made me remember that branch does not have a -n argument. I was mixing `checkout -b` and `branch`. I edited the answer so that it actually works onw.

Comment: In my normal workflow I would rebase each branch on top of the previous, solve any conflicts in the rebase, after which I would to a merge --no-ff and create a clean timeline, but indeed: for a demo branch this is probably overkill. I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

**Is there a way to copy a branch into/as a new branch?**

Yes.

```
git branch demo-features Feature-Branch-1
```

will create a new `demo-features` branch, at this point identical to `Feature-Branch-1` so pointing to the same commit (`Commit2`).

Then, as you rightfully guessed, you can get the other commits by either rebasing or cherry-picking.

I'd suggest cherry-picking ranges here, with

```
git cherry-pick ..Feature-Branch-2
git cherry-pick ..Feature-Branch-3
```

where HEAD is implied in the range (so equivalent to, for the first line, `HEAD..Feature-Branch-2`)

Comment: OW the cherry-pick trick is nice. If I am on the `demo-features` branch, I would do something like `git cherry-pick development..Feature-Branch-2` ?

Comment: If you need the commits to appear on the new branch as separate commits (like they were on the old branches), this is the answer.

Comment: @nathanvda Yes, it would be equivalent. Only commits original to `Feature-2` (in this example) but unknown to `Development` would be picked.